# Is there any Drools plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drools

Have JBoss (or any other Entity) released a Drools plugin for Eclipse ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here goes the steps for how to install drools plugin in eclipse .

1. Start Eclipse
2. Help -> Install New Software
3. In the Work With: or Site: input field, enter: "http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/" and click the "Add" button
4. For the Name you can just enter "Drools"
5. Check the Drools and jBPM checkbox and follow the instructions to get it installed.

I hope this tutorial helpful to [you](http://www.jbug.jp/trans/jboss-rules3.0.2/ja/html/ch02.html).

Comment: Download site for the latest plugin is listed in the Drools dowload page: http://www.drools.org/download/download.html