# How to debug Drools File (.drl) in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide, drools

I am using drools version : 5.5.0.Final

I have added installed drools plugin following below link:
[Is there any Drools plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634439/have-jboss-released-the-drools-pugin-for-eclipse-juno)

and getting nice colorful DRL file editor and drools perspectives.

But the reason I wanted to install drools plugin was to be able to debug and inspect each rules in drl file which does not work.

Basically below steps here doesnt work : http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e8236

I put the debug point in file and run the application in debug mode but it doesnt stop there.

Can anyone please help me in debuging drl files.

Comment: I have never been able to get breakpoints in DRL working myself either. My usual approach has been that if the RHS contains code that's complex enough to need debugging then I write it in a static method in a Java class and call that. Not a great solution though. :-/

Comment: If I am writing complex rules that may require debugging in java code then I am kind of mixing validation by both java and drools. Tutorials/Blogs say debugging possible. I am still looking for help in this

Comment: Don't fear mixing Java and Drools. It's only the LHS where it's generally best to avoid calls to methods in Java classes. The RHS of your rules is just a block of Java code. Whether that code is in a Java class file or inside the DRL file is not that relevant. However, due to the much better IDE assistance for Java classes, you will get more reliable, unit-testable code by putting it in Java classes. You will also get working debuggers. Therefore, if your RHS contains more than a few lines of code, it's much better to put it in a Java class.

Answer (score 2):

Declare Dialect type as dialect "mvel" in drl file. Debug control will move to break points which you have pointed in the respective drl file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a utility class with a debug method:

```
public class DebugUtils {
    public static boolean debugValue(Object value) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then call this method from any rule passing your value and put a breakpoint in this method. This way you will be able to debug your rule.